# Mesos build error

Tags: mesos

I'm begginer on Ubuntu and i'm trying to install Mesos. During the "make" I have this error:

```
../3rdparty/libprocess/3rdparty/glog-0.3.3/.libs/libglog.a(libglog_la-logging.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTCN6google10LogMessage9LogStreamE0_So[_ZTVN6google10LogMessage9LogStreamE]+0x48): undefined reference to `virtual thunk to std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ostream()' 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status 
make[2]: *** [libmesos.la] Error 1 
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/MyName/mesos-0.20.1/build/src' 
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2 
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/MyName/mesos-0.20.1/build/src' 
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

please help me with the start programming in mesos.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason you want to compile mesos yourself?
There are packages available for download here:
http://mesos.apache.org/gettingstarted/
or the [mesosphere packages](https://mesosphere.com/downloads/) allowing you *sudo apt-get -y install mesos*.

Secondly, is there another reason you are trying the 0.20.1 version?
The issue looks like as if there is an issue with the c++ stdlib library. Which compiler/stdlib are you using? Did *./configure* finish successful?

Cheers, 
Joerg

Answer (score 0):

Try to run:

```
/home/MyName/mesos-0.20.1/configure
```

And then:

```
making install
```